# How to extend width and height automatically when the data gets increased

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a jsp page with `<div>` tags and CSS styles. Actually I have given `<div>` tag a width for example as 300px and height for example as 100px. But when there is a large amount of data getting from database the width and height which I mentioned is exceeded and it is overflowing or merging with other `<div>` tags. I will show an image for better understanding.

[image]

In the below image as you can see some part of data is overriding with other part of data and some part is getting outside the border. So my question is how to increase width and height of the fields automatically if there is huge data so that it would not be collided or overridden.
The code I used is as shown below.

```
 #div7{
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            width: 278px;
            height: 40px;
            float: left;
            display: inline-block;
            }
            #div8{
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 328px;
            float: left;
            height: 40px;
            }

<div id="div7">&nbspWorks Address: Same As Above</div>
<div id="div8">&nbspTerms Of Delivery :- <%= termsofdelivery%><br/>
               &nbspAttention :- <%= attention %></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `<table>` tags and given `width="100%"` and `work-break:break-all`.My problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

You could just set your width and height to auto,

```
#id-of-element{

         width:auto;
         height:auto;

}
```

or if you need to have them fixed at a certain width. You could set both containers to a certain percentage.

```
#div1{

    width:50%;

}

#div2{

     width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or you could try to be responsive.

```
#id-of-element{
         width:100%;
         height:auto;
}
```